# Minus value using php

Tags: php

I have the value as `$title =10` and I want to minus it with `01`.So my code is:

```
echo  $minus = round(($title - 01),2);
```

I want the result `$minus = 09` but this code not like this it still have the result `$minus=9`. Anyone help me please,Thanks.

Comment: Numbers cannot have leading zeroes.  You're asking how to format a string.

Comment: are you implementing it as an octal or a string?

Comment: `var_dump($title)` outputs `4`, so it seems despite how you write, as long as it's a valid number, PHP stores it in the most common form. Convert the result to a string so you can add zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that PHP is not strongly typed, and `round()` returns a number, which automatically has the leading zero stripped. Try:

```
$minus = "0" . round(($title - 01),2);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is evaluating your 0-prefixed numbers to their base value -- 04 and 01 are 4 and 1 respectively.

If you want them to be output with a leading 0, try using a [number formatter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), or [string padding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) or simply append them to the string, "0"

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that round() returns an integer. Which means it won't have any 0's before it. If you want it to return 0's before it, try

[str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)(round(($title - 1), 2), 2, "0");

That will make it always append a 0 before the number if it's only 1 number, but if it's 10 or 15 or something, it won't append a 0

Comment: Almost; the problem is that str_pad automatically pads to the right of the string, so if $title were 04, your result would be 30. You can specify `STR_PAD_LEFT` as the fourth argument in str_pad() though, and it would pad to the left.

Comment: So close, I always forget about that until I test it

Comment: I hear you; I ran a quick search for a way to run PHP code online, and I did come across this. It should help in the future: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Answer (score 0):

```
echo str_pad(intval($title) - 1, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

This will pad your result with a 0 if the result is only one digit; otherwise, it will not pad. For a leading zero always, you can replace the 2 with `strlen($title)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$i=04-01;
echo sprintf('%02s', $i);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.